# Displaying video's in mvc from database

Tags: video, browser

I am trying to display videos in view page using asp.net mvc but video is
not playing  because all browsers are not supporting that videos some browsers
is playing and  in some browsers not playing.

I used this code but it is not supporting for all browsers

```
<div class="grid_8">
  <video class="video" poster="http://media.html5media.info/poster.jpg"  width="618"    height="347" controls="" preload="">
     <source src="http://media.html5media.info/video.mp4" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 568px)">
     <source src="http://media.html5media.info/video.iphone.mp4" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 568px)">*@
     <source src="http://media.html5media.info/video.ogv">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, it's a merely lack of knowledge of the HTML.

To support all browsers you will be best served with a plugin that has all that setup, for desktop browsers, mobile browsers, with HTML5 enabled or old browser support...

I can suggest you to go through Google and search for a free **html video player** or any list about [Html Video players](http://spyrestudios.com/10-html-5-video-players/).

This is the one I use the most: http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/